# Is it possible to specify custom layout per package?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

We use `htmlunit` which prints a lot of `error`s with stacktraces. Can I use custom appender layout specifically for `htmlunit` package (with `nopex` option) ? I don't wanna create second appender because it will lead to two log files.

Comment: "I don't wanna create second appender because it will lead to two log files." That is not true. Multiple logback appenders (even across JVMs!) can write to the same log file.